# How to get Control from DataTemplate to ControlTemplate ?

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="Click Me"
                Click="OnClick"
                Name="btn"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>
```

I want to get relevant ListBoxItem when I Click the Button.how to do this ?

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){// How to get ListBoxItem?}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) as follows:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
ListBoxItem item = btn.Ancestors<ListBoxItem>().Cast<ListBoxItem>().First();
```

This finds the first ancestor of the button that is of the desired type.

As an alternative, if you are using databinding, you could inspect the inherited `DataContext` of the `Button` to see which model item it is bound to. That would be my first preference.

Comment: Hey ColinE
I had edited the question can help me with my query?