# Get button in Pivot Header programatically in Windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Summary: I need to retrieve a button (in order to attach a click handler) from a pivot of which template is defined as static resource. How can I do this?

A couple of views contain a pivot control, and style of these pivots are defined in App.xaml as resource.

Here is XAML for Pivot in multiple pages:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Onaylar" Name="pivot" Style="{StaticResource MyPivotStyle}">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="first pivot item">
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource NavyTextColor}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="first pivot item"></TextBlock>
    </phone:PivotItem>

    <phone:PivotItem Header="second pivot item">
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource NavyTextColor}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="second pivot item"></TextBlock>
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="third pivot item">
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource NavyTextColor}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="third pivot item"></TextBlock>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Here is the style for pivot defined in App.xaml (shortened for convenience):

```
<Style x:Key="MyPivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/bg_header.png"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Margin="24,17,0,-7">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/company_name.png" Width="213.75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="140,-20,0,35" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="btnHome">
                                <Image Source="/Assets/btnHome.png" Width="48" Height="48" ></Image>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Foreground="White"  Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I want to do is this:

```
var myButton = GetButtonWithName("btnHome") as Button;
myButton.Click += Handler;
```

However, I cannot get the button. Any solutions?

Comment: You should use command bindings, and not event handlers.

Comment: Binding fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think the main proplem is how to find control in template .

so i think this link can help you :

[How to get Control from DataTemplate to ControlTemplate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860610/how-to-get-control-from-datatemplate-to-controltemplate)